# Bubble / Merge sort type of algorithm: Need proof of correction

Tags: python, sorting

Got this algorithm which is a variation of bubble sort. How does one proof its correctness? Preferably through strong induction. Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names than `A`, `a`, `b` and `k`...

Comment: What do you mean by running time ? Runtie in Landau notation or actual physical time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the time complexity of `some_sort(A)` is `T(n)`.

> some_sort(Array a, a + mid)

Time complexity: T(n / 2)

> some_sort(Array, b-mid, b)

Time complexity: T(n / 2)

> some_sort(Array, a + (mid+1)//2, b - (mid+1)//2)

Time complexity: T(n / 2)

---

```
for i in range(n):
    some_sort(Array a, a + mid)                      # Will be called n times.
    some_sort(Array, b-mid, b)                       # Will be called n times.
    some_sort(Array, a + (mid+1)//2, b - (mid+1)//2) # Will be called n times.
```

```
T(n) = n * T(n / 2) + n * T(n / 2) + n * T(n / 2) + O(1)
T(n) = 3 * n * T(n / 2) + O(1)
```

Using masters theorem we get:

```
T(n) = n^log2(3 * n)
```

Comment: thank you mate! now i just need proof of correctness